How to force data labels to not overlap in ggplot in R Quarto?
I am working with ggplot in R Quarto. I am trying to create a line graph with 3 longitudinal variables (so x = Year, Y = Var1, Var2, Var3). I want to show data labels for all three variables for each year. However, the problem is - data labels overlap, so one can't see all labels. So far, I tried geom_label_repel, but while it tries to separate labels, they still overlap. (As a side note, for some reason, geom_label_repel also puts labels in different positions on a new render). I was wondering if anyone knows a way to automatically make data labels to be separate? (I have many plots like this, so looking for a universal solution rather than for a manual manipulation of this specific plot).
Here the reproducible code I have so far that creates a chart like this:
Chart Example

fontsize: 20pt
echo: FALSE
format:
html:
self-contained: true
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE, message = FALSE) 

library(palmerpenguins)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)


# Creating data 
df <- data.frame( Year = c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2023), 
      Var1 = c(2.01, 3.05, 4.22, 5.29), 
      Var2 = c(2.20, 3.00, 4.10, 5.02), 
      Var3 = c(1.98, 2.43, 4.21, 4.85) ) 

## Identify min and max year
year_1 <- min(df$Year)
year_2 <- max(df$Year)

# Specifying years on the x axis 
year_labels <- c("20", "21", "22", "23")



spline_Var1 <- as.data.frame(spline(df$Year, df$Var1))
spline_Var2 <- as.data.frame(spline(df$Year, df$Var2))
spline_Var3 <- as.data.frame(spline(df$Year, df$Var3))

largest <- max(df$Var1, df$Var2, df$Var3)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Year, y = Var1), size = 3, colour = '#000000') + 
  geom_line(data = spline_Var1, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = "Variable 1"), size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Year, y = Var2), size = 3, colour = '#DC3220') + 
  geom_line(data = spline_Var2, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = "Variable 2"), size = 1) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Year, y = Var3), size = 3, colour = '#005AB5') + 
  geom_line(data = spline_Var3, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = "Variable 3"), size = 1) +
  labs(y = "Variable", x = "Year") + theme(text = element_text(size=14)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "#000000")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=18)) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "#D3D3D3", size = 0.5, linetype = 1)) + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("TEST", subtitle = paste0('Years ', year_1, '-', year_2)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("Variable 1" = "#000000", "Variable 2" = "#DC3220", "Variable 3" = "#005AB5")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(year_1:year_2), labels = year_labels, expand = c(0.03,0.03)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, largest, by = 1), 0.01), expand = c(0.03,0.03)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + theme(legend.title=element_blank()) + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "#000000", margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "#000000", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="#000000"), axis.text.y = element_text(color="#000000")) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = Year, y = Var1, label = paste0(sprintf("%0.2f", round(Var1, digits = 2)))), 
                   color = "#000000", fontface="bold", label.size = NA) + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = Year, y = Var2, label = paste0(sprintf("%0.2f", round(Var2, digits = 2)))), 
                   color = "#DC3220", fontface="bold", label.size = NA) + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = Year, y = Var3, label = paste0(sprintf("%0.2f", round(Var3, digits = 2)))), 
                   color = "#005AB5", fontface="bold", label.size = NA) 




Welcome to SO.  Please make your example minimal by removing everything that is not relevant to your question.  For example your multiple calls to theme() for formatting purposes.  Secondly, if you pivot your data to long format, it will be tidier.  ggplot2, like the rest of the tidyverse, expects tidy data.  This will not only make your code shorter, but may well solve your problem as a single call to geom_label_repel will be able to consider all the labels you want to use, not just those associated with one of your three variables.

"As a side note, for some reason, geom_label_repel also puts labels in different positions on a new render" -- for this use the seed parameter so that each time the graph is rendered with the same output dimensions, it will be consistent.

@JonSpring, oh, thank you! didn't think of 'seed'... reproduces now!

I imagine that each subsequent call to geom_label_repel did not take into account the labels from the previous calls, hence the overlapping. Therefore, as Limey suggested, converting your data to tidy/long will solve your problem, with the added benefit of making the code much shorter.
You can convert your original data frame like so:
df <- df |>
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(Var1, Var2, Var3), names_to = "var", values_to = "value"
  )

And your spline data like so:
splines <- bind_rows(
  list(Var1 = spline_Var1, 
       Var2 = spline_Var2, 
       Var3 = spline_Var3),
  .id = "var"
  )

When done, you can then build the graph like so, with one call per geom:
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = var)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = var), data = splines) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = Year, y = value, label = paste0(sprintf("%0.2f", round(value, digits = 2))))) 

Example with no overlap

This is awesome! Thanks!! Not sure if possible but is there a way to make the labels not cover the lines as much as possible? I.e., if there is an empty space, then force the label to be in the empty space and not overlap with the line?

I'm not sure if there's a way for it to automatically move away from other geoms, but if you want no overlap you could nudge all of the labels up so they are sitting above the lines, for example:
geom_label_repel(aes(x = Year, y = value, label = paste0(sprintf("%0.2f", round(value, digits = 2)))), nudge_y = 1)
